# Is there any special characters that could make printing/displaying a filename dangerous in bash?

Tags: security, bash, special-characters, filenames

So we know that if you're writing bash scripts that you have to be careful of special characters in filenames, things like spaces, and quotes, and newlines. I remember reading somewhere that event displaying/echoing/printing some filenames can be dangerous in bash. Is this true?

Is there any characters one can put in a filename that would be security problem if that filename were displayed/printed/echo'ed, etc.?

Presume I'm running bash on a linux system.

*This isn't actually a problem I have now, nor one that I need to solve, this is more for curiosity and to see if this is a real thing*

Answer (score 1):

When echoing the worst thing that can happen to you is break of `''` and then with the help of `;` you can have arbitrary program execution vulnerability. This is the list of bash special chars:

```
" $ & ' () * ; < > ? [ \ ] ` { | } ~ space tab cr lf
```

Those could present a potential threat depending of their usage context.

Answer (score 1):

On misconfigured terminals and locales, UTF-8 might be dangerous, too. For several years I used a setup where printing UTF-8 text resulted in prepending several characters to the next command I typed.

```
$ cat file.txt
šómé ǧářbáǧě
$ 1;21
```

After typing `ls`, the result was

```
$ 1;21ls
1: command not found
21ls: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as characters, command names could be an issue, given a file call `rm`

```
$ ls               # List files 
rm  somefile  

$ `ls`             # Why aren't my file listed?

$ ls               # Opps where did somefile go?
rm
```

Watch out for what you are really doing in scripts when using `backticks` or `eval`.

Leading hyphens:

```
$ ls
-dumbfile

$ rm -dumbfile
rm: invalid option -- 'd'

$ rm -- -dumbfile   # use -- to delete files containing leading -
```